# How to create a request for a ASP.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need guidance on how I can create a POST request to a web API exposed @http://server:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild' this API takes an XML as input, let's assume the XML is in variable `XMLcontent`

I have done this python as follows, how to convert to C#?

```
import requests
with open("PRE_COMMIT_LA.UM.5.8_524f7fef-5b37-11e7-b4ee-f0921c133f10.xml") as f:
    body = f.read()
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
response = requests.post(
    'http://ctdsapi1:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild', data=body, headers=headers)

print "Printing DEV Pool Response\n"
print response
print "Done...Printing Dev Pool Response\n"

print response.ok
print response.content
```

Comment: Look at `HttpClient` it has methods for `PostAsync()` and you pass it an endpoint and some type of `HttpContent` (in your case youll have to pass `StringContent` since you need to send xml.

Comment: @maccettura - any existing links you can point to?

Comment: [Just the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you most of the way there. Most applicable is the [PostAsXmlAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasxmlasync#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsXmlAsync%60%601(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.String,%60%600)).

```
    // In whatever async method
    // Assuming actual file? Add applicable checks as well.
    var xml = File.ReadAllText(fullPath + "PRE_COMMIT_LA.UM.5.8_524f7fef-5b37-11e7-b4ee-f0921c133f10.xml");

    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
         var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("http://ctdsapi1:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild", xml);

         if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             throw new InvalidUriException("Some error with details."));
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Printing DEV Pool Response\n");
         ...etc.
    }
```